# Set behavior from config?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF client & service solution where I creates the client channel like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < clientSection.Endpoints.Count; i++)
        {
            if(clientSection.Endpoints[i].Name == endpointConfigurationName)
            {
                var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(clientSection.Endpoints[i].Address.ToString());
                var netHttpBinding = new NetHttpBinding(clientSection.Endpoints[i].BindingConfiguration);
                var serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(T)), netHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

                var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(serviceEndpoint);

                break;
            }
        }
```

This works fine but now I need to set the behaviors as well. In the config file the Endpoint have a behaviorConfiguration attribute, this needs to be set above, how is this done?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the behavior to the `ChannelFactory` (Client) object:

```
channelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

And add the the ServceHost (Server) object:

```
   serviceHost.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());
```

You can read more here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702788(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that Behavior do not exists, isntead there is a channelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(IEndpointBehavior). I do not get how to set this from the clientSection.Endpoints[i]. All information exists in the config file but it seems to be hard to read it and set it manually.

Comment: Yes you're right, client (`ChannelFactory`) has `EndpointBehaviors`, and server `ServiceHost` has `Endpoint`, by bad. I'll edit the answer.